# Delete an object using user defined function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, javascript-objects

I am relatively new to JavaScript and trying to learn its basics. I am trying to make a user defined function which will delete an Object which is not declared using var keyword. But I am stuck with this weird behavior.

```
globalObj = {f:56};
Object.deleteObject = function(o){
    return delete o;
}
Object.deleteObject(globalObj); //false
```

So in the above case the object is not deleted. But when i am deleting it using reference to the window object, it gets deleted.

```
Object.deleteObject = function(o){
   return delete window[o];
}
Object.deleteObject("globalObj"); //true
```

Can anyone explain what is happening here?

Comment: You cannot delete an object. You can only delete an objects key/value pair.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce the second snippet](http://jsbin.com/gijupokeme/edit?console)

Comment: Because you are using var keyword to define globalObj. As I mentioned above  I am trying to make a user defined function which will delete an Object which is not declared using var keyword.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`delete` doesn’t delete objects, it removes properties from objects. In your first example you are not deleting the object *from* anything, so it can’t work. And in your second example the object might still exist afterwards if there are other references to it, you’re only deleting the property of `window` which refers to that object.